# splitting directory fileparts into sections using matlab / octave

Tags: string, matlab, octave

I would like to split pathstr into separate parts how can I do this?  See example below.

PS: I'm using octave 3.8.1

```
dpath='tmp/h1/cli/pls/03sox_a_Fs_1000/'
[pathstr,name,ext] = fileparts(dpath)

>>>pathstr = tmp/h1/cli/pls/03sox_a_Fs_1000
```

If all I want is  **03sox_a_Fs_1000** or **pls**
How can I do this?

Please note the filenames will change and could be of different lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [strsplit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) (here using Matlab) to split your string (believe it or not!) using the delimiter `/`:

```
pathstr = 'tmp/h1/cli/pls/03sox_a_Fs_1000'

[Name,~] = strsplit(pathstr,'/')
```

Now `Name` looks like this:

```
Name = 

    'tmp'    'h1'    'cli'    'pls'    '03sox_a_Fs_1000'
```

So you can select the last element using the `end` keyword and curly braces since the output of `strsplit` is a cell array:

```
Name = Name{end}
```

or `end-1` to retrieve `pls`.

This applies to names of any length or format, as long as they are separated by `/`.